# Take data from Multiple Line String and create multiple new Datasets

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have two lists:

Bin Data:

| BinBarcode | Tapes inside |
| --- | --- |
| 12345678 | MA0053L8/nMA0053L8/nMB0030M8 |

Tape Data

| Tape Barcode | Bin |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |

I want to automate when a entery is put into Bin Data. It creates multiple entries into the Tape data for all values seen in the string "Tapes inside"

| Tape Barcode | Bin |
| --- | --- |
| MA0053L8 | 12345678 |
| MB0030M8 | 12345678 |
| MB0030M8 | 12345678 |

How can I do this? Here is my attempt via PowerAutomate:
[image]
But it still cant split the string on the /n and create separate entries.
Any help/ideas would be great

Comment: You have to add the formula as an "expression" from Dynamic data panel. Try this and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the formula as an "expression" from "Dynamic content" panel.

**For Example**:

[image]

Check this documentation for more information: [Introduction to expressions in Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/introduction-expressions/)